# Issue with Rally rest API - .Net

Tags: authentication, rally, ca, user-stories

I'm getting error when trying to import stories using Rally rest API.

I query for project, release and import stories with tags. The program will create tags if it does not exist, if it exists add the tag to user stories. Multiple tags are added to the story after it is created.

This program after it creates 20-30 stories, fails with the error
"You must provide a reference to retrieve data from CA Agile Central.
Parameter name: aRef"

Any thoughts as to how to get this issue resolved?

Thanks,
VV

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without your code.  But my guess is one of your creates is failing for some reason, and you're trying to do something with the CreateResult.Object without checking that it succeeded.

Comment: here is the code snippet: